# pair wise comparison, R code, vector

Tags: r

I want to make pairwise comparisons of 13 data sets (13 independent experiments).  As the cell number differs among experiments it is required to correct the data with x value (the ratio of two cell population sizes).  The vector

```
cellno <- c(2.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.0, 1.6, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9)
```

contains information about cell numbers.  So, I select first value from vector (i.e. 2.3) and divide each other number by 2.3 to get x.

```
n <- cellno [1]
for (i in n:length(cellno)) {print (cellno [i] / n)}
```

However, I want to calculate x for each pair of conditions one by one so I can then run my comparison function for those conditions. It means that I

- calculate x for condition 1 and 2 then make comparison of these conditions and then
- calculate x for condition 1 and 3 make comparison,
- calculate x for condition 1 and 4 and make comparison etc.

When I am done with comparison of condition 1st with other 12 I would like to start the same for the condition 2nd etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I made a list of the values, then used `lapply()` to run comparisons across all 13 values.

```
cellno <- c(2.3, 0.5, 1.3, 1.0, 1.6, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9)
cellno.list <- as.list(cellno)
comparisons <- lapply(cellno.list,FUN = function(x) cellno / x)
```

`comparisions` is a list of 13 vectors. 1st list object is `cellno / cellno[1]`

Comment: Thanks @Chase Grimm